# Trying to randomly choose a phrase

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to help my Mother-in-law out by creating an HTML file with a Javascript function that will randomly select a phrase for her by opening the file on chrome and clicking a `<button>`. However, for some reason, it is not working.

here is what I have for the javascript function within the `<head>`:

```
<script> 
myfunction(array,randInt,item,){
  var array = ["phrase here", "here", "and here"];
  var randInt = randomGenerator(0, array.length-1);
  var item = array[randInt];
  document.getElementById('outputdiv').value = randInt;
}
</script>
```

and then in the `<body>` I have:

```
<button type="button" onclick=myfunction(array,randInt,item,)>click me!</button>
<div id="outputdiv"></div>
```

I tried using an HTML validator and it says there is nothing wrong with the code. However, when I load the webpage the button doesn't do anything. I'm sure there is some stupid simple error/fix somewhere that I'm missing but for the life of me I can't figure out where. please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `randomGenerator` defined? Is there an error in the logs? (In chrome you can hit F12 to open the dev tools and console)

Comment: Note that you need to set document.getElementById('outputdiv').innerHTML to item not randInt

Comment: try `var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a few things wrong with your code

- It's never a good practice to use `onclick` attribute, better use `document.querySelector(...).addEventListener('click', myFunction);`
- The function `randomGenerator` is not defined, i've replaced it with `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)`
- You can't use the attribute `value` to set the inner value of a div, you need to use `innerHTML`
- You are setting the value of `randInt` as what to show in your div, when what you need it `item`.
- You are passing values to your function but you never use them, they are declared in the function itself.
- there a comma that does nothings at the end of your function's parameters.
- When declaring a function, you need to use the keyword `function` in front of it.

I've created a snippet with a working version here :

```js
 function func() {
  var array=["phrase here", "here", "and here"];
  var randInt= Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)  
  var item=array[randInt];
  document.getElementById('outputdiv').innerHTML=item
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', func);
```

```html
<button >click me!</button>
<div id="outputdiv"></div>
```

Comment: > You can't use the attribute value to set the inner value of a div, you need to use innerHTML
Using `innerHTML` is bad practice for the same reason we prefer `car.turnRight()` over `car.do('turn right')`.

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple syntax errors.

- `randomGenerator` isn't thing. You want `Math.random()`
- div doesn't have a `value` property. You want `div.textContent = ...`
- The syntax to declare functions is `function name(params) {}` or `let name = (params) => {};`.
- You don't want to declare your local variables as params.
- You can't pass in non existing params from you HTML.

Some stylistic issues:

- Use dash-case for HTML IDs, e.g. `output-div`.
- Use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` attribute.
- Indent your code. Likewise use spaces around the assignment operator
- use single quotes in JS, double quotes are for HTML
- Use `let` instead of `var`

```js
let generateOutput = () => {
  let array = ['phrase here', 'here', 'and here'];
  let randInt = parseInt(Math.random() * array.length);
  let item = array[randInt];
  document.querySelector('#output-div').textContent = item
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', generateOutput);
```

```html
<button>click me!</button>
<div id="output-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First off, while it isn't possible to tell from your question, I would assume that you haven't defined `randomGenerator`. You can define it as follows to get the desired output:

```
function randomGenerator(floor, ceil) {
  var delta = Math.abs(ceil - floor);
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * delta); // Get a random int between 0 and delta
  return rand + floor; // Shift to start at `floor`
}
```

Next, you're correctly pulling a phrase from the array into `item`, but then you're setting the input to be the index rather than the selected value. Also, you're setting `value`, which only makes sense for `<input>` elements. For a `<div>` you should use `innerHTML` or `innerText` instead.

```
var item = array[randInt];
document.getElementById('outputdiv').innerHTML = item; // Set innerText to item
```

Finally, make sure to wrap your attributes in quotes (and don't use a trailing comma if it's all in-line)

```
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction(array,randInt,item)">click me!</button>
<div id="outputdiv"></div>
```